# The meaning of the structure *to be + said + verb (infinitive)*

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, construction

What are the uses of this structure?

I looked for about it, but I couldn't find something useful.

Can you give me a definition and some examples?

Comment: What structure?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Welcome to our sight for English linguistics. You might be interested in our sister-site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about such lines as these:

```
They are said to be wealthy
She is said to be very beautiful
```

they mean,

```
I hear (or I've heard) they are wealthy 
People say she is very beautiful
```

Other examples:

```
The house is said to be haunted
He is said to be in prison
Prisons are said to be overcrowded 
It is said to be the oldest tree in Scotland
```

We also say:

```
They say he's ill
I gather he's getting better
```